# How to properly import the MetricsServiceV2Client attribute from google.cloud.logging_v2 package?

Tags: google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to set up a locust based framework for ML load test and need to create custom metrics and logs for which the example that I am following is using 'MetricsServiceV2Client' in 'google.cloud.logging_v2' lib.
In the Vertex Workbench on GCP inspite being on v3.0 of the google-cloud-logging lib I am getting an issue of import

```
from google.cloud import logging_v2
from google.cloud.logging_v2 import MetricsServiceV2Client
```

```
error: cannot import name 'MetricsServiceV2Client' from 'google.cloud.logging_v2' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/__init__.py)
```

Interestingly when I test the import in  Google's cloud console I am able to import without any issue. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to the following:

`from google.cloud.logging_v2.services.metrics_service_v2 import MetricsServiceV2Client`

This will work.